# Joomla Session Variables

Tags: django, session, joomla, session-variables, django-context

In Django there is a method called getContext, which retrieves session data, template vars, and everything in the correct "context".

I am now programming in Joomla, and making some components and for debugging I am looking for a way to see all the session vars. Just to look at them and see what is available during specific requests. So, I have searched the api and I know how to get stuff out of the session by keyword, but nothing to see all session store vars.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

get the session or you can get all session $_SESSION or via session table of joomla else you can get by session name using $session->get();

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
```

for get user session

```
$session->get('user');
```

for set any session

```
$session->set('user',$user);
```